# What does the AspNetCoreModule module for IIS implement?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

When hosting an ASP.NET Core website in IIS, we need to install the [ASP.NET Core hosting bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/hosting-bundle?view=aspnetcore-5.0) regardless of compiling the site as a self-contained assembly (which includes the framework and runtime libs).

This requirement does not change when running it out-of-process (where IIS forwards all requests to Kestrel).

What does the AspNetCoreModuleV2 module implement?
Are there any alternatives (apart from not running inside IIS)?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module read it and explain what you don’t understand beyond that.

Comment: @LexLi "a native IIS module that plugs into the IIS pipeline", that explains allot, well it doesn't but it does give some more keywords to search on. Still trying to figure out what the benefits are of self-contained sites if you need to install the entire framework after all. Thanks.

Comment: Found an alternative: [FastCGI](https://github.com/bolner/AsyncFastCGI.NET). It only has examples for Nginx, not sure if it would run on IIS, and it would need some adaption to run the ASP.Net stack. We should have gotten an IIS-specific DLL that adapts to Kestrel instead of needing to install additional stuff. mumble grumble.

Comment: ASP.NET Core does not support FastCGI, so that is a dead end. You either use ASP.NET Core module on IIS (exclusively from the server bundle installer) or use IIS as a reverse proxy (ARR).

Comment: This link should help you understand AspNetCoreModule: [https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Mar/16/ASPNET-Core-Hosting-on-IIS-with-ASPNET-Core-22](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Mar/16/ASPNET-Core-Hosting-on-IIS-with-ASPNET-Core-22).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

> The ASP.NET Core Module is a native IIS module that plugs into the IIS pipeline, allowing ASP.NET Core applications to work with IIS. Run ASP.NET Core apps with IIS by either:
>
> - Hosting an ASP.NET Core app inside of the IIS worker process (w3wp.exe), called the [in-process hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/in-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-5.0).
> - Forwarding web requests to a backend ASP.NET Core app running the Kestrel server, called the [out-of-process hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/out-of-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

So depending on your hosting model, the module will operate slightly different but in the end it will still do the same: It will allow IIS to directly host your ASP.NET Core application. The reason why this is necessary is because IIS itself has [a peculiar way of hosting websites and processing requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture#http-request-processing-in-iis) that is very specific to how classic ASP.NET works.

But since ASP.NET Core neither uses the .NET Framework runtime, nor utilize the classic ASP.NET application model, there needs to be “something“ that stops IIS from applying the default ASP.NET pipeline to ASP.NET Core applications. And that’s the job of the ASP.NET Core IIS Module.

Installing the module basically adds the functionality for the two hosting models to IIS, which can then be activated through the `web.config`—which ASP.NET Core will generate for you.

If you want to host your ASP.NET Core application through IIS, then there is effectively no way around installing *some* module. The ASP.NET Core module is the best way to correctly integrate the app into IIS. If you do not want to use the ASP.NET Core module, then you can also host the app directly on Kestrel, e.g. as a Windows service, and then configure IIS to be a full reverse proxy to your ASP.NET Core application. However, in order to do that, you will need to use the
[Application Request Routing module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) (and its dependency [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)) because IIS does not come with reverse proxy functionality out of the box.

A final note on the ASP.NET Core module: The module really only includes the bits that are required for IIS to host the application. It has no impact on the application code, and you will still need to have the .NET Core runtime either installed separately<sup>‡</sup>, or deploy your application as a self-contained application. You will however not need to regularly update the hosting module since there are very little changes. So usually, it is something you install once and then stop thinking about.

---

<sup>‡ The .NET Core runtime is included in the hosting module by default but you can also install *just* the hosting module on its own, which is just under 2 MiB.</sup>

Comment: I'm a bit tinkering about the "You will .. not need to regularly update the hosting module since there are very little changes." What about the dotnet core security patches that come out (quite often)? The version of the hosting module is linked to a specific dotnet core version so just for keeping the dotnet runtime and hosting module in-sync I would be tempted to install the latest hosting bundle each time a security patch comes out. bad idea ?

Comment: @AardVark71 _“The version of the hosting module is linked to a specific dotnet core version”_ – No, that’s not the case. The module will just provide the ability to work with the runtime, but it’s not linked to a specific one. In case of self-contained applications, the included runtime will be used; in case of framework-dependent applications, the globally installed framework will be used. And you can update the latter without having to reinstall/update the IIS module.

Comment: @AardVark71 But of course, always updating the *hosting bundle* is still a fine thing to do since the bundle also includes the latest runtime. So even if the IIS module hasn’t changed (which it usually the case), the runtime will still be updated. It’s just that you don’t *need* to install the hosting bundle all the time; just updating the runtime is usually enough (or in case of self-contained applications, republishing with the updated SDK).